# Can't programmatically save download files in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter web app which downloads files from an API on a different subdomain. I can get the file but my code doesn't save anything and fails silently. I have read that the HTML 5 `a.download` function doesn't support CORS [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatically-downloading-files-browser/). The headers show that I am getting a file of the correct size. Is there any workaround to save this file? I don't get a manual prompt either. Is that because the file name is not in the Content-Disposition header? Data Type is deduced programmatically using the mime package and is correct as `audio/mpeg`.

Here is my Flutter code

```
/// web.dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as universal_html;

var logger = Logger(
  printer: PrettyPrinter(),
);

Future<void> downloadFile(
    {required String token,
    required String url,
    required String fileName,
    required String dataType}) async {
  try {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Accept': 'application/octet-stream',
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
    };

    final http.Response r = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);

    final data = r.bodyBytes;

    final base64data = base64Encode(data);

    final a =
        universal_html.AnchorElement(href: '$dataType;base64,$base64data');

    a.download = fileName;

    a.click();

    a.remove();
  } catch (e) {
    logger.d(e);
  }
}
```

Logger output for the headers is

{
│    "content-length": "14992480",
│    "content-type": "application/octet-stream"
│  }

My API log

```
2023/09/06 19:28:07 [my-api/BsANaSUJ8g-000239] "OPTIONS http://api.mydomain.com/audio_file/download/6 HTTP/1.1" from 172.19.0.2:42264 - 200 0B in 39.741µs
2023/09/06 19:28:10 [my-api/BsANaSUJ8g-000240] "GET http://api.mydomain.com/_audio_file/download/6 HTTP/1.1" from 172.19.0.2:42264 - 200 14992480B in 2.915921409s
```

API CORS setup

```
r := chi.NewRouter()

r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
r.Use(middleware.Logger)
r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
r.Use(middleware.URLFormat)
r.Use(render.SetContentType(render.ContentTypeJSON))
r.Use(cors.Handler(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*"},
    AllowedMethods:   []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
    AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Accept", "Origin", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token", "X-Requested-With", "User-Agent", "Cache-Control", "Pragma", "Content-Disposition"},
    ExposedHeaders:   []string{"Link", "Content-Length"},
    AllowCredentials: false,
    MaxAge:           300, // Maximum value not ignored by any of major browsers
}))
```

Comment: What sort of value are you using for `dataType`?

Comment: `dataType: lookupMimeType(user.downloadFileName) ?? '');` = "audio/mpeg".

Comment: It looks like you are missing the word `data` then. The href would have to be: `data:audio/mpeg;base64,aaaaaaaa....`

Comment: That's the answer! Please write it up.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have access to the server code. Have you tried setting the Content-Disposition header?

```
  'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
  'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="$filename"',
  'Content-Type': 'whatever/whatever',
```

Rather than `click`, try `dispatchEvent`

```
html.AnchorElement(href: href)
  ..download = filename
  ..dispatchEvent(html.Event.eventType('MouseEvent', 'click'));
```

Finally, check the format of your Data URI. It should be in the form:

```
data:<type>;base64,<base64data>
data:audio/mpeg;base64,aaaaaaa......
```